# jQuery: add elements until a particular height is reached

Tags: jquery, height

I have a column on the left with a few articles. This height is dynamic and changes based on the published content. I have a column on the right that is typically shorter. I'm pulling 3 large elements and then another 5 small ones and I want to fill in the right column with extra elements until it's close to the height of the column on the left.

So I pull all the large elements (3) and assume that this is shorter than the left. Then I pull the other 5 with a class attached to hide them (for those w/o JS). Now I want to iterate through the 5 elements and keep adding until I can't add anymore without making that column longer than the one on the left. Here's what I have so far:

```
var hLeft = $('#home-col-left').outerHeight();
var hRight = $('#home-col-right').outerHeight();
var hRunning = hChecking = 0;

$('#home-col-right').children().each( function () {
    hChecking = hRunning + 60;
    if (hChecking < hLeft) $(this).removeClass('hidden');   
    hRunning = hRunning + $(this).outerHeight();
})
```

The problem is that I can't check the height of the element while it's hidden so I use the hChecking var to assume that the new ones are about 60 pixels tall. This isn't ideal because they can be less or more than that.

Any way to get this working while still allowing the elements to be hidden for folks without JS? Thanks!

Comment: Why not simply set the right column height to be equal to the left one and then `overflow-y:hidden` it?

Comment: Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/liho1eye/nSATB/

Comment: The boxes that are being added change height and they are text so if I set the overflow to hidden, it will likely just cut some of the text off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works:

```
var containerDiv = $('#someElement');
while( containerDiv.height() < 500 ){
    $('<p>Test</p>').appendTo(containerDiv);
}
```

Comment: You might want to consider caching the `$('#someElement')` jQuery object.